# Replace percent (symbol and value) and brackets

Tags: php, regex

I receive from the client a string like this one:

```
"a, b, c, d 5%, e, f, g 76%, h (string,string), i"
```

I want to create a regExp that can remove from the string 5%, 76% (and any other possible percent value n%) and the brackets (bracket opening is replaced by comma). The desired result is:

```
"a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, string, string, i"
```

Is this possible with PHP?

Comment: Yes it is possible using regular expressions `preg_replace`, what have you tried till now ?

Comment: Being not so good at regexp, I was looking for someone who can help me with it.

Comment: this is quite simple, you need 2 replace operations, one that replaces with an empty string and one that replaces with a comma. Maybe you are interested in [the basics of regular expressions](http://wp.me/p2pTzU-4).

Comment: @Battery Everyone is a beginner once, you can try playing here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ , and then convert your correct regex to PHP syntax

Comment: ok, thanks everyone for not killing me   ;-)   I'll study a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with PHP,
use this function :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

You will need to write a regular expression to match your criteria.

Answer (score 3):

```
$cleaned = preg_replace('/[%()]/', '', $input)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to replace all occurrences of '%20' in filenames, and '/[%20]/' solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of the braces is a bit unclear, but if I assume there's no other opening an closing braces, use this:

```
$line = "a, b, c, d 5%, e, f, g 76%, h (string,string), i";
$line = preg_replace('/\s+\d+%/', '', $line);
$line = preg_replace('/\s*\(/', ', ', $line);
$line = preg_replace('/\s*\)\s*/', '', $line);
$line = preg_replace('/,(\S)/', ', $1', $line);
echo $line;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use this code:

```
preg_replace('/ *\d*\%/','', 'a, b, c, d 5%, e, f, g 76%, h (string,string), i');
```

Here is [example](http://regexr.com?30tb9) (switch to replace tab and clean the replace text)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "a, b, c, d 5%, e, f, g 76%, h (string,string), i";
$string = preg_replace('/\s+\d+%|\)/', '', $string);
$string = str_replace('(', ',', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', ', ', $string);
```